# How to add an image in Hugo's front matter

Tags: image, templates, frameworks, hugo

I am trying to add an image in Hugo's front matter to be displayed when it's called in my HTML. The current scenario that I'm working with is that I have a list page listing projects and a single page that is of a single project.

In my .md file I would like to reference the location of the corresponding image to be displayed on both locations (list and single page).

I am not sure how to do this. I've tried using ".Params" I have found in other posts, but I am unable to show the image on the webpage.

I have my images in the static folder under a sub-folder named images

This is my current setup:

```
<div class="projects">
    {{ range .Pages }}
    {{ with .Params.featured_image }}<img src="{{ . }}">{{ end }}
    {{ end }}
</div>
```

The "range pages" is to loop over all of my project pages and display the name, title and description. I took out the name and description for brevity.

and my .md file for each individual project page:

```
---
title: "Text Based Adventure"
description: "A simple text based adventure game that gives a nod to the 80s style terminal games"
draft: true
featured_image : “images/textAdventure.png”

---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the *webpage* you're referring to is [list.html](https://gohugo.io/templates/lists/) or [single.html](https://gohugo.io/templates/single-page-templates/)

### `single` and `list` page

According to your setup's syntax,

```
{{ range .Pages }}
    ...
{{ end }}
```

there is no way to use it in `single.html`, but only in `list.html`. Although both `list.html` and `single.html` are [Page](https://gohugo.io/variables/page/#page-variables) Variable, the difference is their `range Pages`. `Pages` may have something, but `single.html` will definitely not have something.

---

I'm not sure if you understand the difference between `list.html` and `single.html`. I'll describe it in unorthodox vernacular,

- `list.html`: like a **folder**
- `single.html`: like a **file** in a folder.

suppose your files, like below,

- `posts/lesson1.md`
- `posts/lesson2.md`

When you visit those URL,

- `http://localhost:1313/posts/`   # rendered page is `list.html`
- `http://localhost:1313/posts/lesson1`  # rendered page is `single.html`
- `http://localhost:1313/posts/lesson2`  # `single.html`

### Image

If your image location is `images/textAdventure.png`

then the picture is located in `static/images/textAdventure.png`

### drafts

Your drafts is `True` so you need [--buildDrafts or -D](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/usage/#test-installation) to see the page when you run.

---

### do not rely on other themes

The last thing I want to emphasize is that front matter only provides some variables to the template. Template implement is the key. If you are a beginner in Hugo, I suggest that you do not rely too much on the themes provided by others and suggest that you try it yourself first before you consider quoting someone else's theme.

If you are very clueless after reading the official documents, you can first consider watching simple tutorials [video](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLAZ4kZ9dFpOnyRlyS-liKL5ReHDcj4G3) and then go to the official documents to get into the situation

Answer (score 1):

Found this question via Google - The answer is it becomes `.Params.Featured_Image` but it seems more normal to use snake-case as in `featuredImage` and `.Params.FeaturedImage`